# ¿Por qué al crear un objecto autogenera id repetido? Error de generación de id

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data, id, autoincremento

tengo un error al autogenerar los id, estoy creando una pregunta y tiene una lista de opciones, esta es la pregunta que recibe el backend (Spring) y llega desde el Front (Angular):

```
{
   "idpregunta":"",
   "enunciado":"Enunciado de prueba",
   "urlImg":"",
   "idImg":"",
   "nombreImg":"",
   "opciones":[
      {
         "enunciadoopcion":"Opcion a",
         "idopcion":"",
         "respuesta":false
      },
      {
         "enunciadoopcion":"Opcion B",
         "idopcion":"",
         "respuesta":false
      },
      {
         "enunciadoopcion":"opcion C",
         "idopcion":"",
         "respuesta":true
      },
      {
         "enunciadoopcion":"opcion d",
         "idopcion":"",
         "respuesta":false
      }
   ]
}
```

Aunque tambien probe en crear una Pregunta son las opciones ya que el error es el Id, pero aunque el Id es cero (0), me salta este error.

```
2022-06-24 09:37:30.636 DEBUG 2172 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into pregunta (enunciado, idImg, nombreImg, urlImg) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
2022-06-24 09:37:30.690 TRACE 2172 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [Enunciado de prueba]
2022-06-24 09:37:30.691 TRACE 2172 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - []
2022-06-24 09:37:30.691 TRACE 2172 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - []
2022-06-24 09:37:30.691 TRACE 2172 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - []
2022-06-24 09:37:30.844  WARN 2172 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23505
2022-06-24 09:37:30.844 ERROR 2172 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pregunta_pkey"
  Detail: Key (idpregunta)=(18) already exists.
2022-06-24 09:37:31.093 ERROR 2172 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [pregunta_pkey]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pregunta_pkey"
  Detail: Key (idpregunta)=(18) already exists.
```

Esta es la clase Pregunta y la Clase Opcion.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pregunta")
public class Pregunta implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idpregunta;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String enunciado;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String urlImg;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String nombreImg;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String idImg;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pregunta")
    private List<Opcion> opciones;

    @JoinTable(
            name = "cartilla_pregunta",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idpregunta", nullable = false),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idcartilla", nullable = false)
    )
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Cartilla> cartillas;

    public void agregarCartilla(Cartilla cartilla) {
        if (this.cartillas == null) {
            this.cartillas = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        this.cartillas.add(cartilla);
    }

    public  void removerCartilla(Cartilla cartilla){
        this.cartillas.remove(cartilla);
        cartilla.getPreguntas().remove(this);
    }

    public List<Cartilla> obtenerCartillas(){
        return this.cartillas;
    }

    /** Getter y Setter **/

@Entity
@Table(name = "opcion")
public class Opcion implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int idopcion;

  @Column(length = 80, nullable = false)
  private String enunciadoopcion;

  private boolean respuesta;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "idpregunta")
  private Pregunta pregunta;

  /** Getter y Setter **/
```

En el codigo ya funciona el editar, me permite editar aunque modifique el enunciado de pregunta u opcion, la respuesta de opcion e incluso la imagen (urlImg, nombreImg, idImg), pero el crear por alguna razon se duplica, me preocupa que tengo mas tablas similares, que aun estan funcionando pero temo que dejen de trabajar.

Comment: Deberías agregar tu clase donde se muestra la lógica  de negocio del insert, ademas te sugiero que te revises la sequence en tu base de datos, también en lo posible agrega tu tabla para ver como esta creada.

Comment: No se que paso, pero aunque tenia 25 preguntas en la tabla, la tabla decia que la secuencia  el ultimo id de la tabla era inferior a 25, le indique cual era el ultimo y ya funciono de nuevo. Gracias